# Open an XML file in windows with a stylesheet applied without editing the XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm looking for a way to view an XML file with an XSL stylesheet applied without having to modify the XML file to reference the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated any real requirements, other than being able to view XML with a stylesheet applied without modifying the XML to specify the stylesheet.

You could write a simple Java/C#/PHP/whatever application that reads the XML and parses it, creating either a DOM object or a JAXB class hierarchy, does the same with the XSL, applies the transformation and writes out the transformed XML.  You can then view this in an appropriate viewer (that would be a function of the transformation -- typically it would be a text editor, a web browser, it could be PCL that you feed to a printer, anything really).

Comment: I don't have any real requirements.  Ideally, I'd like an XML viewer where I could open an XML and drag an XSL onto it or select from a menu of frequently used transforms to apply.  Something simple, like that.

Comment: Look at Altova's XMLSpy.